# Why is document.getElementById not needed?

Tags: javascript, variables

**1) Question 1**

The following example works without using "document.getElementById('myId')". Why is that and is it OK to skip "document.getElementById('myId')"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript question</title>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    myId.style.color = 'red';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id=myId>
<p>Make this color red.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**2) Question 2**

I usually store browser-objects to reduce DOM traversal (see example below). Will it be more DOM traversal if I dont store the ID in a variable or is it some how already a variable?

```
window.onload = function(){

var myId = document.getElementById('myId'); /* stored ID that will be used multiple times */

myId.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/2zr5Lgfo/

Comment: When a lot of such elements are required in a web page it might not be a good idea to store everything.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> The following example works without using "document.getElementById('myId')". Why is that and is it OK to skip "document.getElementById('myId')"?

Because browsers dump references to all elements with `id`s into the global namespace, using the `id` as the variable name. (Technically, as the *property* name on the global object; properties of the global object are global variables.) I strongly recommend **not** relying on it and using `document.getElementById` (or similar) instead. The global namespace is **really crowded** and there are lots of other things there which can conflict.

For instance, if you have

```
<div id="foo">...</div>
```

and

```
function foo() {
}
```

Then just using `foo` in your code will give you the function, not the element.

Similarly if you have

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

...and use `name` in your code, you'll get the window's name (a string), not the `HTMLInputElement` for your `id="name"` field.

This business of dumping references to the elements into the global namespace is covered in [§5.2.4 of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), which in this case is largely documenting what browsers have done for a long time.

> Will it be more DOM traversal if I dont store the ID in a variable or is it some how already a varible?

It's already a global variable per the above, so there's no additional DOM traversal. In a deeply-nested function there may be more scope chain traversal, but that's unlikely to be a major issue.

---

But again, I strongly recommend **not** relying on the automatic element globals. Instead, wrap your code in a scoping function (as you've shown), and get the elements on purpose with `getElementById`, `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, etc., as appropriate. If you rely on the automatic globals, odds are eventually you'll get bitten by a conflict. But this is opinion.

Note that looking up elements with `getElementById` is ***really really fast***, so caching references is not usually necessary for performance reasons (you may want to do so for other reasons, like coding convenience). Looking things up with selectors (`querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`) is a bit slower, but I'd say worry about it when/if there's a problem. :-)

Comment: I have a special pattern on how I write IDs and functions. In my case there will be no conflict. Also I will never share my code with other programmers. If all modern browsers support the technique and they are planing to continnue to do so, I see no reason to not try it out. But, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I discovered the technique by accident a few weeks ago and have been using it ever since. It works with all browsers, including mobile browsers.